# Como usar Adobe Flash Player en 2021?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chrome, adobe-flash

Trabajo en una empresa donde todo nuestro sistema esta hecho en Adobe Flex y para poder visualizar las apps hechas en Adobe Flex, se tiene que usar Adobe Flash Player, que en 2021 se dejara de usar en todos los navegadores supuestamente. La migración la empezamos hace 1 año a HTML, pero el sistema es tan grande que aún no hemos terminado. Mi pregunta es, alguien mas esta teniendo este problema? Como podre usar adobe flash en 2021 en algún navegador? Cabe destacar que este sistema es de uso interno de la empresa, es decir, no sale a la web. Cualquier información me tengan me seria de ayuda, ya que en la web no encuentro respuestas. Gracias.

Comment: https://veriskope.com/2020/01/flash-2021-seven-valid-options-to-keep-using-your-flash-application/

No parece que haya muchas alternativas. La que menos cuesta es guardar un navegador antiguo y usarlo solo para esa app (ya que tendrá problemas de seguridad para todo lo demás)

Comment: Si, esa es mi idea, bloquear la actualización de firefox y seguir usando una versión antigua, pero también he leído que aunque tengas una versión antigua no funcionara a partir de 2021.

Comment: Buenas buenas probale con esta extension https://ruffle.rs/#releases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la empresa donde trabajo, tambien tenemos este inconveniente, nuestro plan de accion es el siguiente.

1. El plugin de flash cuenta con una validacion que llama la fecha de tu maquina y verifica que no sea > 12-01-2020; por lo que se debe configurar un archivo mms.cfg el cual esta en la documentacion de adobe, lo vi en este tuto (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4bualXiMSg&t=673s)
2. la ubicacion del archivo y las listas blancas estan alli.
3. Adicional de tener una version de firefox enterprise, (tambien tengo kmeleon
   instalado).

Hice las pruebas necesesarias y funciona. Pero como mencionan los demas, dependemos de las actualizaciones y tener una version estable tanto del SO como del navegador. Sigo buscando
alternativas. Ya que aun nos falta un proyecto mas por migrar.